# Angular - How to call a function from inside an object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm wondering how can I call a function inside an object. I created here a [quick demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rf4bmx?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Basically the idea is that I get some number from the user, I filter that number looking for the same value in my object and then I run a specific function.

btw, maybe there is some nicer way to code that, webstorm suggested me to create functions outside my component idkw

Thanks for any suggestions :)

Comment: Instead of `filter` you can use normal `for` or `forEach`

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly why they'd prefer using functions defined outside the scope. Unless you wish to reuse the function elsewhere, you could define the functions as inline arrow functions.

```js
datePeriods = [
  {
    name: "Currenty",
    value: 1,
    setDate: () => { console.log('current date') }
  },
  {
    name: "Last",
    value: 2,
    setDate: () => { console.log('last date') }
  },
  {
    name: "Custom",
    value: 3,
    setDate: () => { console.log('custom date') }
  }
];
```

And `Array#filter` is used to generate an array based on a certain condition. Since you wish to only run the function when the condition is met and exit, you could use `Array#some` instead.

```js
onSelectedDate() {
  this.datePeriods.some(data => {
    if (this.selectedDate === data.value) {
      data.setDate();
      return true; // <-- skip the following iterations
    }
  });
}
```

I've updated your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8c3xwp?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

---

Note: While you could also use `Array#forEach` here, it'd continue to run even after the condition is met. Thus would lead to unnecessary iterations. `Array#some` on the other hand would short-circuit as soon the condition is met.

Comment: Thank you! + good protip about Array, will use that

Comment: @Jan: Please note I've included a `return true;` inside the `some` callback. Without it other elements would be iterated as well.

Answer (score 2):

You probably wanna have reference to the function rather than the function call in the Object. Something like `setDate: currentDate` rather than `setDate: currentDate()`. Your code works after this change.

**Improvements:**

Use in-place arrow functions in the object like so

```
datePeriods = [
  {
    name: "Currenty",
    value: 1,
    setDate: () => console.log(1)
  },
  {
    name: "Last",
    value: 2,
    setDate: () => console.log(2)
  },
  {
    name: "Custom",
    value: 3,
    setDate: () => console.log(3)
  }
];
```